# I'm getting NaN value on my daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

there. I just updated my daterangepicker on my website.It's working really fine on fields for posting ( starts on / ends on ), but...In my profile, I had my date picker with `value="{{$user->dob}}"` which gaves me the date of birth of my profile. Now, I updated my datepicker from DOB with this line :

```
<input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" value="{{ $user->dob }}">
```

but I'm getting NaN at value and when it's open up it looks like that :

[image] .

**Here is my script**

```
 $(function() {
  $('input[name="dob"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: 1901,
    maxYear: 2099,
  }, function(start, end, label) {


  });
});
```

I'm using Daterangepicker : http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: What plugin are you using? Please provide a link.

Comment: I'm using daterangepicker. Here is a link : http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: What is the actual value of `$user->dob`?

Comment: Actually, value is NaN. This should be date of birth of my profile, from database.

Comment: Yes i meant, what is the value in the DB?

Comment: 2019-04-17 this is from DB.

Comment: Is value showing in html for this line ?? <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" value="{{ $user->dob }}"> inspect and check

Comment: yes, in console I actually have this : `<input type="text" name="dob" value="2019-04-17">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the locale in your settings as described here:

http://www.daterangepicker.com/#example2

Because you need to specify in which format your date is passed to the component

Comment: Should I use this ? ` locale: {
          cancelLabel: 'Clear'
      }`

Comment: For what you need you I think you should use the `format` locale settings in this way `"format": "YYYY-MM-DD",`

Comment: There is also an useful tool at bottom of docs http://www.daterangepicker.com/#config